# Если я только что задал вопрос, у моего вопроса моментально один просмотр

Tags: поддержка

Чей это просмотр ? Считается, что во время написания вопроса я его уже посмотрел?)) И мне кажется, что далее , если я через немаленькие промежутки времени просматриваю вопрос, он набирает просмотры (с учетом того, что браузер не меняю и даже не закрываю)

Answer (score 3):

Первый просмотр — ваш. Дальше вопрос набирает просмотры других участников.

Comment: Самому тоже можно несколько раз увеличить просмотры.

Answer (score 3):

Как уже ответил Nick, первый просмотр - просмотр автора вопроса. Хотя мне кажется, [ноль бы там смотрелся не менее логично](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284946/339911). При этом существующее поведение [не стыкуется с количеством просмотров профиля](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291588/339911), что странно. А однажды я наблюдал значение "1 просмотр" на чужом вопросе, видимо какие-то проблемы с кешированием, больше такого не удалось повторить.

О том, как работает счетчик просмотров [можно подробнее почитать на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/339911). Вкратце, счетчик увеличивается, если с предыдущего вашего захода на страницу вопроса прошло больше 15 минут.

Comment: Ну это ведь не дает мне достоверные данные о том, сколько человек просмотрело мой вопрос, если учесть, что он будет расти от моих же просмотров (через каждые 15 минут).  Если сообщество решило, что просмотры дают полезную информацию, значит стоит их сделать более точными, особенно это нужно, когда вопрос задается по какой-то узкой специализации и этих просмотров итак будет не много.  Стоит наверно сделать предложение .

Comment: @Turalllb Вы планируете каждые 15 минут открывать страницу с вопросом? Обеспечение уникальности потребует хранить id всех посетителей, при этом кто-то заходит без авторизации и для таких случаев нужно брать IP. Всё это потребует хранения дополнительной информации и лишней нагрузки на поиск при выяснении необходимости увеличивать или нет счётчик просмотров. А что если вопрос изменился или добавился/изменился ответ, такой просмотр должен учитываться, если участник его уже смотрел до изменения? Мне кажется, что защита от накрутки просмотров в целом имеется, но, безусловно, она не идеальная.

Comment: Да можно ведь сделать проще - убрать свой просмотр. Почему вы считаете, что он нужен? Написал я вопрос , пока просмотров 0 , вроде логично и обыденно для нас. А тут один просмотр и ощущение, что за тобой кто-то следит и ждет твоего вопроса) Ну и потом из-за этого же накрутка просмотров самим же собой, что немного уменьшает точность этого параметра.

Comment: @Turalllb защита примерно такова, каков защищаемый объект. В лучшем случае накруткой просмотров можно заработать виртуальный значок. Это не ахти какая выгода, и если человек может организовать просмотры страницы с тысяч разных IP, то ему наверняка неинтересен такой значок.

Comment: @Turalllb так я тоже за 0 просмотров в начале. В ответе это указал и ссылку привел. Но идея не возымела основоположников.